# Pandas: rolling window calculation requiring input from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate the CAPE ratio for individual stocks (link below but unlikely you'll need to know it to answer the question).

[Link to CAPE definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cape-ratio.asp)

My dataframe has quarterly data for earnings per share ('EPS') and the CPI ('CPI Value').  I wish to calculate the 10 year (40 quarters) inflation-adjusted average PE.

So for each row of the new column the calculation requires:

- a 40 period lookback
- ratio of CPI at start of period over current CPI (starts at 1 at the start of each lookback window and gradually decreases to account for inflation)
- this CPI ratio multiplied by the current EPS value
- the average of all these multiplications for the window

eg- CAPE on day i:

CAPE[i] = Average of ((CPI[i-40] / CPI[i-40]) * EPS[i-40]), (CPI[i-40] / CPI[i-39]) * EPS[i-39], ... , (CPI[i-40] / CPI[i]) * EPS[i]))

Seems fairly clear that 'rolling' needs to be used, possibly with an 'agg' function.

I am struggling to do this since the calculation requires two columns from the dataframe instead of just one and I am not sure how to access them inside the rolling function.

Also don't think a 'helper' column is useful since the values change for each lookback window.

Toy example code below:

`df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(100))`

`df['CPI Value'] = 1. + (df.index / 100.)`

`df['EPS'] = 10.`

& here's my non-working attempt:

`df['CAPE'] = df.rolling(40).agg(lambda x: ((x['CPI Value'][0] / x['CPI Value']) * x['EPS']).mean())`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to work with pandas even though it seems relatively trivial, kept getting tripped up with syntax or not passing through the correct parameters.

Numpy-extended's rolling_apply function seems to have worked though.

```
from numpy_ext import rolling_apply

def func(a,b): return np.mean((a.iloc[0] / a) * b)
df['inf_adj'] = rolling_apply(func, 40, df['CPI Value'], df['EPS'])
```